# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre los archivos 'x.routing.ts' y 'x.routing.module.ts' en angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, routes, routing, angular13

Al ver distintos videos e información veo que algunos estructuran las rutas por componentes por lo cual tengo la duda en saber la diferencia de usar los archivos
con terminación *.routing.ts* y *routing.module.ts*

Dejo un ejemplo

> usuario.routing.ts

> usuario-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Es un tema de buenas prácticas y no repercute en el funcionamiento de Angular. El deber ser es nombrarlo por `usuario-routing.module.ts`

Puedes tener `usuario.routing.ts` y `usuario-routing.module.ts` con esta información

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Y al importarlo no tendrás ningún problema sin importar el nombre.

Pero, Angular tiene un [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#feature-modules) de cómo debemos nombrar un módulo, como estructurar la carpeta del proyecto, cómo debemos nombrar las clases... etc.

Reitero, es un tema de buenas prácticas y no tiene repercusión en el funcionamiento del framework